# 台 tái = term of address? Is this address?

Tags: meaning

The dictionary has a meaning like this:

`台 tái` = platform, unit, term of address

What does “term of address” mean? Does `tái` mean address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When `台` means 'platform', you may see it in `月台` (train platform), `舞台` (stage), `電台` (radio station), `電視台` (TV station) etc.
2. When `台` is a unit, you may see it in `一台貨車` (a truck), `一台電腦` (a computer); it is a counter for bulky objects.
3. `台` may also be an abbreviation for Taiwan, as in `台式` (Taiwanese style).
4. `台` as a term of address (address here means speaking or writing to someone, not a location) is possible, although somewhat archaic / formal. In the past it is very common to attach `～鑒` after the addressee's name in letters. Depending on their status relative to yours, you choose the correct character before `鑒`: e.g., `台鑒` for peers, `鈞鑒` for reverent people, and `雅鑒` for ladies. You also end the letter with salutations like `即候台安` or `順頌台祺`, again depending on your status. Put simply, `台` is a general term of address for peers. If you're interested you may refer to [this link](http://twowin.com.tw/gogo_card/chinese/p7.htm) to see an exhaustive list on the correct terms of address in various situations.

Comment: 台式could also be “stationary”：台式电脑 means a PC rather than laptop