# How do 台, 鑒 compound to mean Salutation of a formal business letter, but after someone's name?

Tags: etymology

1. Why's [台   a term of address](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/43420)?
2. How do 台,鑒 semantically appertain salutations in a formal letter?
   Alone 台 and 鑒 don't mean  salutations or greetings in a formal letter. [張三](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_placeholder_names_by_language#Chinese)***台*** and 張三***鑒*** don't make sense!
3. Why are names FOLLOWED BY 台鉴? Why doesn't 台鉴 antecede names? By comparison, 尊敬的 antecedes names! You must write 尊敬的張三, NOT 張三尊敬的! See why I'm wildered?

[台鉴的解释及意思-汉语词典](https://cd.hwxnet.com/view/kgmiafjoedbndmdl.html)

> 请对方审察﹑裁夺的敬辞。后常用于书信。
>
> [a form used after the name in the salutation of a business letter] 敬辞,用于请对方阅览

[台鑒_百度百科](https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E5%8F%B0%E9%91%92/390252)

> 請對方審察﹑裁奪的敬辭。後常用於書信

To keep this post short, I don't quote [Baidu](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1771535068627774100.html).
I couldn't find 鑒 listed in Axel Schuessler, *ABC Etymological Dictionary of Old Chinese*  (2007). Apprise me if you can! But I used the Pinyin for 鑒, and lighted upon this listing containing 鑑 on p 305 — Please see the red underline —  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%91%92) touts 鑑 as the Shinjitai for 鑒. Thus this listing appears germane?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on this:

- 台 -- 古時祇有地位尊貴之人，例如祭師，統治者才有資格站在高台上
- 鑒 -- 能鑒賞，鑒定某物表示你對某物有完全控制及持有權，不單是祇能看看
- 台鑒 --> 請(高台之上之的)你，(詳細)鑒閲

台 - 提高對方地位

鑒 - 強調對方權力

台鑒 - 自謙之詞 (you supposedly only use it with people in a higher position than yours, but you can use it with your peer to show humbleness)

When a lawyer address the court, he is actually addressing the judge

I would translate 台鑒 as "for your highness to inspect"

*Similarly: 垂鑒 = lower yourself (look down from your high position) to inspect*

Comment: "you supposedly only use it with people in a higher position than yours." I can't find references to this. All I have found says it is used for people with same level as you. [link1](http://twowin.com.tw/gogo_card/chinese/p7.htm),[link2](https://www.3people.com.tw/%E7%9F%A5%E8%AD%98/%E6%9B%B8%E4%BF%A1%E7%B5%90%E6%A7%8B%E5%8F%8A%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E/%E5%B0%B1%E6%A5%AD%E8%80%83%E8%A9%A6-%E5%8F%B0%E5%8C%97%E6%8D%B7%E9%81%8B%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8/9b7c9c3c-48bb-4f90-bc5a-29301924982d).

Answer (score 0):

"鑒"的釋義:

**Noun -**

1. 鏡子。同「鑑」。 例《詩經·邶風·柏舟》：「我心匪鑒，不可以茹。」
2. 視察的能力、見識。 例《梁書·卷二七·到洽傳》：「樂安任昉有知人之鑒。」
3. 借鏡。 例《詩經·大雅·蕩》：「殷鑒不遠，在夏后之世。」

**Verb -**

1. 照。 例 漢·秦嘉〈留郡贈婦詩〉三首之三：「明鏡可鑒形。」
2. 明察、審察。 例 南朝梁·劉勰《文心雕龍·樂府》：「季札鑒微於興廢。」

**3.** 書信用語。用於開頭的稱謂之後，表示請人看信的意思。如：「xxx鈞鑒」、「xxx大鑒」、「xxx臺(台)鑒」。

"XXX臺(台)鑒" is used in a respective manner in the letter but different from words indicating direct respect towards the receiver, such as "尊敬的XXX". It is on two locations of a letter:

1. On the Envelop after the name of the receiver. In here, it is equivalent to the modern words "收" and "啟", but more formal, and possesses the sense of "自謙", as 台 has the meaning of "yours" and "the receiver is a step higher than the sender" (Note, 對人尊稱的敬辭。如：「兄臺」、「尊臺」).
2. At the beginning of the letter to address the receiver. Similar to the above, it reflects "自謙" with the word "台", and by asking the receiver "明察"、or "審察" uses the word "鑒", which normally is conducted by somebody in a higher position only.

Comment: I don't think you answered my questions 1, 2.

Comment: I adequately answered both.  I do not aware of the association of 台 with "address" except its use and association with letter explained in my answer. Please provide your reference/example of Q1 otherwise.